# Try-Catch JSONArray Nullpointer catch nothing

Tags: android, try-catch

I want to catch nothing if the jsonarray is empty. Here is my code:

```
try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject customer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int sender = customer.getInt("sender");
                        Log.e("Customer", "is " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                        TextView tv[] = new TextView[jsonArray.length()];
                        tv[i] = new TextView(ChatActivity.this);
                        Log.i("Sender", "is " + sender);
//                    Log.i("Curernt ID", "is " + currentUserId);
//                    Log.i("Logged in", " ID is " + sharedPrefsUser.getInt(SharedPrefsInformation.ID_FROM_LOGGED_IN_USER, -1));
//                    Log.i("")
                        if (sharedPrefsUser.getInt(SharedPrefsInformation.ID_FROM_LOGGED_IN_USER, -1) == sender) {
                            tv[i] = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.messae, null);
                        } else {
                            tv[i] = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_other, null);
                        }
                        tv[i].setText(customer.getString("message"));
                        Log.e("Message", "is " + customer.getString("message"));
                        linearLayoutWithMessages.addView(tv[i]);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return;
            }
```

But now the App will crashed because the jsonArary is empty (Nullpointer).
Any suggestiones, to call a Toast or something to prevent the crash of the app?
Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check before the for if the `jsonArray` is empty or add a new catch for Null Pointer

```
try {  
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {  
        JSONObject customer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ...
} catch (JSONException e) {
    return;
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    //do something
}
```